# How do I get the results of the Plucky Query inside my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm missing something simple - I *do not* want to access the results of this query in a view.

Here is the query:

```
@adm = Admin.where({:id => {"$ne" => params[:id].to_s},:email => params[:email]})
```

And of course when you inspect you get:

```
@adm is #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery:0x007fb4be99acd0>
```

I understand (from asking the MM guys) why this is the case - they wished to delay the results of the actual query as long as possible, and only get a representation of the query object until we render (in a view!).

But what I'm trying to ascertain in my code is IF one of my params matches or doesn't match the result of my query *in the controller* so I can either return an error message or proceed.

Normally in a view I'm going to do:

```
@adm.id
```

To get the BSON out of this.  When you try this on the Decorated Query of course it fails:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Querying::DecoratedPluckyQuery:0x007fb4b9e9f118>)
```

This is because it's not actually a Ruby Object yet, it's still the query proxy.

Now I'm fundamentally missing something because I never read a "getting started with Ruby" guide - I just smashed my way in here and learned through brute-force.  So, what method do I call to get the results of the Plucky Query?

Answer (score 0):

The field `@adm` is set to a query as you've seen. So, to access the results, you'll need to trigger execution of the query. There are a variety of activation methods you can call, including `all`, `first`, and `last`. There's a little documentation [here](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#all).

In this case, you could do something like:

```
adm_query = Admin.where({:id => {"$ne" => params[:id].to_s},:email => params[:email]})
@adm_user = adm_query.first
```

That would return you the first user and after checking for `nil`

```
if @adm_user.nil?
   # do something if no results were found
end
```

You could also `limit` the query results:

```
adm_query = Admin.where( ... your query ...).limit(1)
```

Comment: While this does seem to be the answer - it's not what I was hoping.  I know there is only a single result from my query, so I didn't wish to limit it or operate on it in any way.  But alas, it seems I must.

Comment: Why does that matter? Once it's queried, it's queried. It won't need to be queried again.

Comment: The point is I know I'm only going to get a single result, but I wanted to fuzzy query based on a where statement instead of a "find_by_id" or similar.  But I have to use the find_by_X method, and this is ok as I haven't tripped myself up searching for an ID that I don't know yet.  Sometimes when I don't know the ID I want to use but I do know a value in another field it's easier for me to search by that - but this means my logic is poor to begin with I guess...